# Could I pass a StringIO object as a "file" argument to a Linux command line?

Tags: python

Some commands on Linux receive a file as an argument. (cat, grep, sed, awk,...)
How can i pass a StringIO object as a "file" argument? (because i don't want to write it to file on disk, then explicitly pass to these commands)
Or i need other kind of "in-memory file" object?

Answer (score 2):

[Create a pipe](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.pipe), [connect the read end](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.dup2) to your process within [`preexec_fn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630354/20862), pass the device file to the command, and [copy the `StringIO` contents](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to the write end.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about "connect the read end"? Thanks you!

Comment: Use `os.fdup2()` to copy the FD from the read end of the pipe to a known FD, or pass the value of the existing FD to the command.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how can I pipe a StringIO object as a file argument.

The commands you have listed also take input from stdout as the file argument.

such as:

```
mypyscript.py | cat
```

or

```
cat < mypyscript.py
```

What you're doing here is writing the StringIO objects contents to stdout in mypqscript.py

Assuming fo is a StringIO object with contents, in the appropriate place in your script in your script have:

```
   sys.stdout.write(fo.getvalue())
   sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: The `std*` arguments in `subprocess` must be a constant from `subprocess`, `None`, a FD, or a file backed by a real FD.

Comment: @Mike Ramirez: very few linux commands can use "-" instead of a real FD.

Comment: @Locke: But almost all of them can take `/dev/stdin`.